# Multiple buttons and search placement in header for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a search input and three buttons on the same line in jQuery Mobile, but it is turning out to be really frustrating. Here is the code I am trying:

```
<div data-role="header" class="header">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search-header" value="" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" />
    <a href="#menu_page" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>
    <a href="#menu_page" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog">View</a>
    <a href="#menu_page" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog">Menu</a>
</div>
```

With a CSS of this:

```
.page .header .ui-input-search
{
    margin-right: 90px;
}
```

I am ok with using the default icons that come with JQM, but the placement ends up looking like this though:

[image]

I even tried putting a controlgroup around the buttons only and also around the buttons and input box, but put the buttons below the search box.

How would I achieve this in JQM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working!

```
<div data-role="header" class="header">
    <input type="search" name="search" value="" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" class="search-header" />
    <div class="ui-btn-right">
        <a href="#menu_page" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>
        <a href="#menu_page" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog">View</a>
        <a href="#menu_page" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog">Menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the margin? Right off I see that could cause some problems. Also you might want to float your images.

I have a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/cncpts/B4Pa6/2/

Comment: I did try removing the margin. Your sample breaks with the latest JQM: http://jsfiddle.net/B4Pa6/3/ . Also seems a little hacky since floats are trying to override absolutes.